# Angularjs routing, nothing happens

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to implement routing into a empty Angular project but the routing doesn't seem to react to the different urls.
index.html, index.html#/, index.html#/audience just seems to load the index page and the only console output is "routing".

I've been testing this in Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu 13.10 and Angular version 1.2.7

**app.js**

```
var App = angular.module('analyticsApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'analyticsControllers',
]);


App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    console.log("routing");
    $routeProvider.when("/audience", {
        templateUrl: 'partials/audience.html',
        controller:  'AudienceCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise ({
        redirectTo: '/audience'
    });
}]);
```

**controllers/audience_controller.js**

```
var analyticsControllers = angular.module('analyticsControllers', []);

analyticsControllers.controller('AudienceCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
console.log("audienceCtrl");
}]);
```

Comment: Do you have a `ng-view` on your page?

Comment: Seems about right. Do you include all necessary files? Maybe you can extract the relevant code into a Plunker, so we can have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

in **index.html** was required to make the routing work as intended.

Comment: I lost my day struggling with this, but you saved me another day of struggling ;)

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thanks for sharing! You probably should mark this answer as correct.